# Error sending text on iPhone programmatically, wrong format on the phone number?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a pretty peculiar problem with sending a SMS from the iPhone programmatically, here is how I want my code to work/look:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *textController = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        textController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        {
            [textController setBody:[managedObject valueForKey:@"Message"]];
            [textController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[managedObject valueForKey:@"Number"], nil]];
            [self presentModalViewController:textController animated:YES];
        }
```

However, the value I store in `[managedObject valueForKey@"Number"]` is retrieved from the address book in an earlier stage and have some pretty weird formatting, for example "073-339 53 46". I know that iOS stores phone numbers as strings, but somehow I am not allowed to send to a number which is formatted that way (I recieve a sigabrt - "`[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1204b0`").

But if I hard code the number as (without spaces and dashes):

```
[textController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0733395346", nil]];
```

It works as a charm - but kind of defeats the purpose of retrieving the numbers from the address book.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *textController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

textController.messageComposeDelegate = self;

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    [textController setBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"Message"]]];
    [textController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"Number"]], nil]];
    [self presentModalViewController:textController animated:YES];

    [textController release];
}
```

u have to convert those message and number to NSString.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! However - I find this rather strange, because I already store them as strings in Core Data...? Do by any chance have an idea of why you would have to do it this way?

Comment: in core data the string may store differently .it u want to use them elsewhere then u should use like simple